# Enabling Heroku's Free SSL with CloudFlare

Tags: ssl, heroku, cloudflare

I'm trying to enable my Heroku app's free SSL. I am currently on the Hobby pricing plan.

Currently, on CloudFlare my DNS is pointing towards domain.herokudns.com opposed to something like my-app.herokussl.com. I noticed I don't have/can't access `server.crt` or `server.key` to manually configure it like this page insists: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl

I've tried disabling/enabling and refreshing certs but it continues to fail.

Can someone point me in the correct direction please?

Comment: Your DNS shouldn't point to `my-app.herokudns.com`, but rather _`my.domain.tld.herokudns.com`_. Is that how yours is set? What is the output of `heroku certs:auto`?

Comment: It does. Sorry for the wrong first post.

Comment: Okay, no problem. What about the output of `heroku certs:auto`?

Comment: @Chris 'Failed'

Comment: Would you mind sharing the domain you are trying to use?